# HTTP/1.1 426 Upgrade Required

Tags: http, websocket, terminal, server, upgrade

When trying to connect to localhost (with Terminal), I got this answer:

> HTTP/1.1 426 Upgrade Required 
>   Server: WebSocket++/0.3.0-alpha4

How can I respond to that to Upgrade?

Comment: What exactly is the request? And does the response come with a response body?

Comment: Hi Julian, I'm trying to connect to localhost to run an app. I used command-line "netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen" to figure out which port number should I use and the terminal returned several localhost listening. I used curl -v http://localhost:[NUMBER]/ and the first localhost number I tried returned the message:  < HTTP/1.1 426 Upgrade Required
< Server: WebSocket++/0.3.0-alpha4
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
< 
* Closing connection 0      One of the other localhost I tried seems working now. Sorry if my "coding language" is not precise, I'm a beginner!

Answer (score 11):

You are clearly connecting to a WebSocket server, not a plain HTTP server

> Server: **WebSocket**++/0.3.0-alpha4

The [WebSocket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) starts with an HTTP-based request/response handshake where the client asks the server for permission to upgrade communications to full duplex WebSocket messaging.

The 426 response means that initial handshake is not requesting a proper WebSocket upgrade.  Per [RFC 6455 Section 4.1 Client Requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.1):

> Once a connection to the server has been established (including a connection via a proxy or over a TLS-encrypted tunnel), the client MUST send an opening handshake to the server.  The handshake consists of an HTTP Upgrade request, along with a list of required and optional header fields.  The requirements for this handshake are as follows.
>
> 1. The handshake MUST be a valid HTTP request as specified by [RFC2616].
> 2. The method of the request MUST be GET, and the HTTP version MUST be at least 1.1.
>
> ```
> For example, if the WebSocket URI is "ws://example.com/chat", the first line sent should be "GET /chat HTTP/1.1".
> ```
>
> 3. The "Request-URI" part of the request MUST match the /resource name/ defined in Section 3 (a relative URI) or be an absolute http/https URI that, when parsed, has a /resource name/, /host/, and /port/ that match the corresponding ws/wss URI.
> 4. The request MUST contain a |Host| header field whose value contains /host/ plus optionally ":" followed by /port/ (when not using the default port).
> 5. The request MUST contain an |Upgrade| header field whose value MUST include the "websocket" keyword.
> 6. The request MUST contain a |Connection| header field whose value MUST include the "Upgrade" token.
> 7. The request MUST include a header field with the name |Sec-WebSocket-Key|.  The value of this header field MUST be a nonce consisting of a randomly selected 16-byte value that has been base64-encoded (see Section 4 of [RFC4648]).  The nonce MUST be selected randomly for each connection.
>
> ```
> NOTE: As an example, if the randomly selected value was the sequence of bytes 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0a 0x0b 0x0c 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f 0x10, the value of the header field would be "AQIDBAUGBwgJCgsMDQ4PEC=="
> ```
>
> 8. The request MUST include a header field with the name |Origin| [RFC6454] if the request is coming from a browser client.  If the connection is from a non-browser client, the request MAY include this header field if the semantics of that client match the use-case described here for browser clients.  The value of this header field is the ASCII serialization of origin of the context in which the code establishing the connection is running.  See [RFC6454] for the details of how this header field value is constructed.
>
> ```
> As an example, if code downloaded from www.example.com attempts to establish a connection to ww2.example.com, the value of the header field would be "http://www.example.com".
> ```
>
> 9. The request MUST include a header field with the name |Sec-WebSocket-Version|.  The value of this header field MUST be 13.
>
> ```
> NOTE: Although draft versions of this document (-09, -10, -11, and -12) were posted (they were mostly comprised of editorial changes and clarifications and not changes to the wire protocol), values 9, 10, 11, and 12 were not used as valid values for Sec-WebSocket-Version.  These values were reserved in the IANA registry but were not and will not be used.
> ```
>
> 10. The request MAY include a header field with the name |Sec-WebSocket-Protocol|.  If present, this value indicates one or more comma-separated subprotocol the client wishes to speak, ordered by preference.  The elements that comprise this value MUST be non-empty strings with characters in the range U+0021 to U+007E not including separator characters as defined in [RFC2616] and MUST all be unique strings.  The ABNF for the value of this header field is 1#token, where the definitions of constructs and rules are as given in [RFC2616].
> 11. The request MAY include a header field with the name |Sec-WebSocket-Extensions|.  If present, this value indicates the protocol-level extension(s) the client wishes to speak.  The interpretation and format of this header field is described in Section 9.1.
> 12. The request MAY include any other header fields, for example, cookies [RFC6265] and/or authentication-related header fields such as the |Authorization| header field [RFC2616], which are processed according to documents that define them.
>
> Once the client's opening handshake has been sent, the client MUST wait for a response from the server before sending any further data.
>
> The client MUST validate the server's response as follows:
>
> 1. If the status code received from the server is not 101, the client handles the response per HTTP [RFC2616] procedures.  In particular, the client might perform authentication if it receives a 401 status code; the server might redirect the client using a 3xx status code (but clients are not required to follow them), etc.  Otherwise, proceed as follows.
> 2. If the response lacks an |Upgrade| header field or the |Upgrade| header field contains a value that is not an ASCII case-insensitive match for the value "websocket", the client MUST *Fail the WebSocket Connection*.
> 3. If the response lacks a |Connection| header field or the |Connection| header field doesn't contain a token that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the value "Upgrade", the client MUST *Fail the WebSocket Connection*.
> 4. If the response lacks a |Sec-WebSocket-Accept| header field or the |Sec-WebSocket-Accept| contains a value other than the base64-encoded SHA-1 of the concatenation of the |Sec-WebSocket-Key| (as a string, not base64-decoded) with the string "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" but ignoring any leading and trailing whitespace, the client MUST *Fail the WebSocket Connection*.
> 5. If the response includes a |Sec-WebSocket-Extensions| header field and this header field indicates the use of an extension that was not present in the client's handshake (the server has indicated an extension not requested by the client), the client MUST *Fail the WebSocket Connection*.  (The parsing of this header field to determine which extensions are requested is discussed in Section 9.1.)
> 6. If the response includes a |Sec-WebSocket-Protocol| header field and this header field indicates the use of a subprotocol that was not present in the client's handshake (the server has indicated a subprotocol not requested by the client), the client MUST *Fail the WebSocket Connection*.
>
> If the server's response does not conform to the requirements for the server's handshake as defined in this section and in Section 4.2.2, the client MUST *Fail the WebSocket Connection*.
>
> Please note that according to [RFC2616], all header field names in
> both HTTP requests and HTTP responses are case-insensitive.
>
> If the server's response is validated as provided for above, it is said that *The WebSocket Connection is Established* and that the WebSocket Connection is in the OPEN state.