AWS API gateway with Python Websocket
I am trying to create a chat app using Flask Websocket hosted on EC2 and expose using API Gateway. My App has both HTTP as well as SocketIO connection. My request flow is Browser -> API Gateway -> NLB -> EC2 . I created another API Gateway of type Websocket and but I am not able to connect to that API gateway. I tried testing with postman websocket request. I am able to connect to EC2 , I am able to connect to NLB (both on host 8765) but not able to conenct to AWS Gateway. I have followed all the posible permutations on API Gateway Websocket but not sucessfull. From post man I am getting HTTP 426 . Any pointers what should I do or document I can refer to. Below is my connection code from Front end

I am not an expert, but I came across this Q&A that might be helpful to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324473/http-1-1-426-upgrade-required

I also found this one: https://enlabsoftware.com/development/how-to-create-real-time-chat-applications-using-websocket-apis-in-api-gateway.html
